# Why do we register blueprints in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I was just wondering what's it mean to register something in Python/flask. Here is the code that I've seen in [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/blog/#create) flask tutorial that shows registering a blueprint.

```
from . import blog
app.register_blueprint(blog.bp)
```

I am a Python and Flask programming noob so I wanted to figure out the concept behind this. Why do we do this in Python programming?

Comment: Somehow the app has to know that the blueprint exists and should be served.

Comment: Does the flask page on blueprints help? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/ Essentially they are intended to provide common features across multiple projects. Say a login page that is common between flask applications.